# how does qt 5.7 use gstreamer on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qt, gstreamer

I'm a newbie on Qt stuff (Using Qt 5.7), phonon backends are no longer supported and Qt uses gstreamer. But how does qt make the gstreamer's pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

It uses C API of the GStreamer.